# Extract Text Files in Google Cloud VM

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Noob and beginner here. Just trying to learn the basics of GCP.

I have a series of Google Cloud Buckets that are text files. I also have a VM instance that I've set up via GCP.

Now, I'm trying to write some code to extract the data from Google buckets and run the script via GCP's command prompt.

How can I extract GCP buckets in Python

Comment: Your questions seems a little unclear to me, so I'm assuming you have several text files within a Google Cloud Storage bucket(s) and you're trying to write a script on a Google Compute Engine Instance that will download the specified files. Do you want to invoke this script from the Google Cloud Shell (i.e. outside of the instance)?

Comment: I guess you are looking for solutions to process some data files which is stored in Cloud Storage. With Dataflow in GCP, you could write data pipeline in Python with Apache Beam SDK to get data from Cloud Storage, process it, and output it. GCP Dataflow is a managed service that it manage the VM-instance and the Apache Beam runtime for you. You only need to focus on developing the data pipeline program.
Here is a simple example about doing word count with apache beam. https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount_minimal.py

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the [Listing Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) and [Downloading Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python) GCS methods with Python; in this way, you will be able to get a list of the objects stored in your Cloud Storage buckets to then extract them into you VM instance. Additionally, keep in mind that it is important to verify that the [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) that you implement to perform these tasks, has the required [roles assigned](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) in order to access to your GCS buckets, as well as [provide the credentials to your application](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) by using environment variables or explicitly pointing to your service account file in code.

Once you have your code ready, you can simply execute your Python program by using the 
`python` command. You can take a look on [this link](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup) to get the instructions to install Python in your new environment.